# Removing a row in a matrix, by removing an entry from a possibly different row for each column

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a vector of values which represent an index of a row to be removed in some matrix M (an image). There's only one row value per column in this vector (i.e. if the image is 128 x 500, my vector contains 500 values).

I'm pretty new to MATLAB so I'm unsure if there's a more efficient way of removing a single pixel (row,col value) from a matrix so I've come here to ask that.

I was thinking of making a new matrix with one less row, looping through each column up until I find the row whose value I wish to remove, and "shift" the column up by one and then move onto the next column to do the same.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a solution which avoids loops and is thus faster to write and to execute. It makes use of [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), and exploits the fact that you can remove a matrix entry by assigning it an empty value (`[]`):

```
% Example data matrix:
M = [1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20];
% Example vector of rows to be removed for each column:
vector = [2 3 4 1 3];

[r c] = size(M);
ind = sub2ind([r c],vector,1:c);
M(ind) = [];
M = reshape(M,r-1,c);
```

This gives the result:

```
>> M =
     1     5     9    14    17
     3     6    10    15    18
     4     8    11    16    20
```

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Thanks for the +1! Empty indexing is so much fun :-)

Comment: Good answer.  Lucky for you I'm on vacation.  :p

Comment: @chappjc So you too enter here on vacation. StackOverflow has us :-D